# Update SELECT query using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query like below.

```
SELECT Date
     , Co 
FROM Table1
```

I want to use a case statement to update `Co = 'Client'` when `Co = 'XYZ'`. I do not to update this info in the original `Table1`. I just want the change to reflect in my `SELECT` statement.

`Table1` :

```
   Date   |  Co 
------------------
 1-1-2015 |  ABC
 1-2-2015 |  XYZ
 1-3-2015 |  AAA
 1-4-201  |  CCC
```

I want my `SELECT` statement result to look like below

```
   Date   |  Co 
------------------
 1-1-2015 |  ABC
 1-2-2015 |  Client
 1-3-2015 |  AAA
 1-4-201  |  CCC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT [Date]
     , CASE WHEN [Co] = 'XYZ' THEN 'Client'
            WHEN [Co] = 'PQR' THEN 'Partner'
            ELSE [Co] 
       END AS [Co]  
FROM [Table1]
```

[**Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have one more question. What if I have two cases like when Co = 'PQR' Then 'Partner'?

Comment: @Sam : I've updated the answer, the logic is the same, you just add another `WHEN` with your condition.

Comment: Thank you notulysses. It's a big help.

Answer (score 0):

In different syntax:

```
SELECT  [Date],
        CASE [Co]
            WHEN 'XYZ' THEN 'Client'
            WHEN 'PQR' THEN 'Partner'
            ELSE [Co]
        END AS [Co]
FROM Table1
```